# Does C#.NET Have Anything Equivalent to Java's Sealed Package Feature for JAR Files?

Tags: java, c#, namespaces, package

By default, packages in Java can span multiple JAR files - but this can be prevented through the use of [Package Sealing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html). Is there an equivalent feature for namespaces in C# to prevent them from spanning multiple Assemblies, *i.e. DLL files*?

Comment: Not that I know of.  *Packaging* in Java and in .NET are very different.  You may want to look at *Strongly Named Assemblies*.  They represent a very different concept and have different use cases.  However, they can, for example, provide you with a path towards version consistency (which was the example in the link you provided).

Comment: By the looks of it, Packages equate to .NET Namespaces. And I am honestly not sure that you even *can* append to them in the first place. You can have the code split up over multiple source files sure, but adding stuff to the namespace in a programm that meerely references the compiled .dll? I am not sure.